# .NET access error INSERT INTO

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to insert textbox text into a database using VISUAL STUDIO here is my code:

```
Dim usernme, passwrd As String
usernme = REG_USER_USERNAME.Text
passwrd = REG_USER_PASSWORD.Text
Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Login.accdb"

myConnection.Open()

Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO Admins (USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES('" & usernme & "','" & passwrd & "')"
MsgBox(sqlQry)
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myConnection)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

myConnection.Close()
```

But i get an exception error including this:

> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Whats wrong with my code, i have quotation marks round the values too!

Comment: A) Never ever concat strings to make SQL - use parameters B) PASSWORD is a reserved word in access so escape it `[Password]` or dont use reserved words as column names C) never ever store passwords as plain text - hash them.  D and E) Please read [ask] and take the [tour]  You should also learn to dispose of things

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is that *Password* is a reserved word in Access. Thus:

```
Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO Admins (USERNAME, [PASSWORD]) VALUES('" & usernme & "','" & passwrd & "')"
```

That said, as you do a direct concatenation with non-sanitised user input, *do* follow the advices posted by @Plutonix.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way.

```
*Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Requires: Imports System.Data.OleDb
        ' ensures the connection is closed and disposed
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=""C:\your_path_here\InsertInto.mdb"";" & _
            "Persist Security Info=False")
            ' open connection
            connection.Open()
            ' Create command
            Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand( _
                "INSERT INTO Table1([inputOne] , [inputTwo] , [inputThree]) " & _
                "VALUES (@inputOne, @inputTwo, @inputThree);", _
                connection)
            ' Add the parameters with value
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputOne", TextBox1.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputTwo", TextBox2.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputThree", TextBox3.Text)
            ' you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
            ' execute the command
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Insert is done!!")
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class*
```